# How To calculate time complexity of selection sort

Tags: sorting, selection

Time complexity of Selection Sort(Worst case) using Pseudocode:

```
'Selection-Sort(A)

1 For j = 1 to (A.length - 1)

2   i = j

3   small = i

4   While i < A.length

5     if A[i] < A[small]

6       small = i

7     i = i + 1

8   swap A[small], A[j]
```

First step will occur n-1 times (n is length of array). So the second and third. I am stuck with 4th step whether it will occur n! times or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic operation for this algorithm is the comparison at line 5, in the inner loop. Both loops are executed ≈ n times, i.e. the basic operation is executed n*n times ≈  n^2.

The time complexity for selection sort is O(n^2). It is same for worst best and average cases.

You should have look at the link below it gives a good rundown on selection sort. 
https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/sorting-algorithms/a/analysis-of-selection-sort

Hope this helps.

edit:

When analyzing the time complexity of non recursive algorithms,

- Decide on parameters indicating the input size
- Identify the basic operation
- Set up a sum indicating the number of times the basic operation is executed
- Establish its order of growth
- Give an asymptotic estimation

In this case the input size will be the size of the array, the basic operation is of comparison, the arithmetic sum would be,

Σ1≤ j ≤n-1 Σj≤ i ≤n or Σ0≤ j ≤n-2 Σj+1≤ i ≤n-1

This will evaluate to (n-1)(n/2) which is asymptotically O(n^2).

For more information i would recommend these two books,

1. Introduction to Design and Analysis of Algorithms - Anany Livitin
2. Introduction to Algorithms - Coreman

Comment: In the link you attached, cases are added and not multiplied (while loop (n+1)(n/2)). Can you explain it why?